# django admin: How to get all values from 2 models with same FK

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to access to onetomany of related model field (2nd hierarchy). This is my scenario:

`RealState` (model)

- owner (fk)

`CheckingAccount` (model)

- balance
- owner (fk)

`Owner` (model)

In my `RealState` admin I want to view a `selectbox` of Owner's `CheckingAccounts`...

Any idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, show what you've already tried (i.e. code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 In CheckingAccount model make sure u have an admin_link func that works

somthing like this :

```
def get_admin_absolute_url(self):
    if self.pk:
        return resolve_url('admin:checkAccounts_change', self.pk)

def admin_link(self):
    if not self.pk:
        return ''
    return ('<a href={}>{}</a>').format(self.get_admin_absolute_url(),
                                        self.name)
```

## 2 in CheckingAccount add this func:

```
    def get_all_onwers(self):
        return Owner.objects.all()
```

## 3 In RealState model add this func:

```
    def get_all_onwers(self):
        return Owner.objects.all()
```

## 4 In Owner model add this func:

```
    def get_all_CheckingAccount(self):
        return self.CheckingAccount_set.all()
```

## 5 In RealState admin:

```
    def get_all_owners_CheckingAccount(self, obj):
        all_checks_accounts = []
        for owner in obj.get_all_owners():
            all_checks_accounts.append(','.join(checkAccount.admin_link() for chechAccount in owner.get_all_CheckingAccount()))
        return all_checks_accounts

    get_all_owners_CheckingAccount.allow_tags = True
```

that's it, maybe you will need to filter some results that are shown twice or more, and edit the form for prompting the checkbox